# unable to return html page in flask

Tags: html, flask

I have a flask project where I have an endpoint that returns  `return ''' <h1> Inserted succesfully . Click this link to <a href = "moviehome.html"> go to home page </a> </h1>  '''` where I want to click on the href text `"go to home page"` to return to my home page . However when I click on it I get a
`404 URL not found on the server`  error . I also tried `<a href = "{{url_for('home')}}">` inserting the name of my endpoint but the result was the same

My home endpoint :

```
#home page
@app.route('/')
def home():
    
    return render_template('moviehome.html')
```

I would appreciate you help with this issue . Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return '''
<h1> Inserted succesfully . Click this link to
  <a href = "{{ url_for('home') }}"> go to home page </a>
</h1>
'''
```

you are returning just a **plain string** with `docstring` letteral, the `jijna2` expression is not parsed but interpreted as string.

the solution is to use **string concatenation** like

```
return '''
<h1> Inserted succesfully . Click this link to 
  <a href = " ''' + url_for('home') + ''' "> go to home page </a>
</h1>
'''
```